# send restricted page access link to user after filling the elementor form in WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, elementor

I have a wordpress site and iam using elementor pro. I have created a form using elementor. When the user submits the form the link shall be sent to the user provided email in the form by which the page can be accessed for a desired period of time. I dont want any registration plugins to be used in my site. just a form with name email company name.

The link shall expire after a certain time. If the user tries to access the page with page url they should be get redirected to a certain page. I currently have a redirect setup in actions after submit to that page but with url the page can be accessed and i cannot confirm the valid emails the users are putting in the form.

Iam using elementor pro and also have crocoblock plugins like jetengine.

I have tried membership plugins and user registration plugins but none of them work. as it requires users registration but I don't want that. I want it to be a simple code which checks the form submission activity and by form id extract the email field and create a unique link for the page and send it via mail to the user.

Comment: Hey @mohwebsolutions! Welcome to the community! Consider making your question more pleasant to read (add subheadings, bold & italic highlights, etc.).  This will make more people want to read your question at first glance, and you will get more answers quicker.  Pleasure to have you. 